# Dynamic Array with multiple CountIfs

Tags: arrays, excel, dynamic, excel-formula, countif

Is there a way how to get multiple results out of `COUNTIF(S)`?

I have a "compliance checklist" table of resources, where each row represents one resource. Based on the periods in columns H-J I get ✕ if person is non-compliant and ✓ if everything is OK.

Current formula for compliance calculation:

```
=COUNTIFS(INDEX($H$8#,(ROW(H8)-ROW($H$7)),,1),"✕")
```

This current formula needs to be in each line separately and I would like to change it to dynamic array formula to have only 1 formula in first row. However I have tried, it seemed to me that it is not possible, I always get `!SPILL` or another type of error.

[image: Compliance checklist]

Comment: If you would post your data in text form, rather than image, that would be easier. See the link for how to insert a table into your question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support

Comment: @Dave, I agree a table of data would be nice, however you can't catch a spilled array in any table on SO unfortunately. By that I meant it wouldn't help us trying to work out a formula with the [spilled range operator](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/spilled-range-operator-3dd5899f-bca2-4b9d-a172-3eae9ac22efd) #.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think what you are trying is possible in a row-wise fashion through `COUNTIFS()`. Btw, "SPILL" error is because a formula wants to spill data but is not able to do so since those cells are allready filled with data.

Either way, you could try `MMULT()` instead:

[image]

Formula in `G8`:

```
=MMULT(--(H8#="✕"),{1;1;1})
```

If you want to, you can make the 2nd parameter dynamic too:

```
=MMULT(--(H8#="✕"),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(H8#),,1,0))
```